# Whether there is a Riemannian metric on $S^2\times S^2$ with positive scalar curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

Whether there is a Riemannian metric on $S^2\times S^2$ with positive scalar curvature ?

If there is a such metric, how make the section curvature is positive under some suitable flow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g$ be the standard metric on $\mathbb S^2$. Then the product metric $g\times g$ on $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb S^2$ has positive scalar curvature (and non-negative sectional curvatures). Indeed pick any $g_1, g_2$ with positive curvatures would do the job.

I hope you have luck finding such a flow, as that would prove (or disprove?) the [Hopf conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_conjecture).

Some references: [Survey by W. Ziller](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/papers/SurveyMexico.pdf), [survey by B. Wilking](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.3091v1.pdf)